# Random int without importing 'random'

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

is there a way to let the program select a random number between say 1 and 1,000 without importing `random`?

Comment: Why can't you just import `random`? You could start writing your own random number generation code, but why would you?

Comment: Sure, just write your own PRNG, or perhaps read from the system's (e.g. /dev/random).

Comment: Of course there is: http://xkcd.com/221/ (trivially translated into Python). Put another way, you'd be more likely to get useful answers if you told us where you were going with this.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [`random` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/random.py):

```
def randint(a, b):
    "Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points."
    return a + randbelow(b - a + 1)

def randbelow(n):
    "Return a random int in the range [0,n).  Raises ValueError if n<=0."
    if n <= 0:
       raise ValueError
    k = n.bit_length()
    numbytes = (k + 7) // 8
    while True:
        r = int.from_bytes(random_bytes(numbytes), 'big')
        r >>= numbytes * 8 - k
        if r < n:
            return r

def random_bytes(n):
    "Return n random bytes"
    with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as file:
        return file.read(n)
```

Example:

```
print(randint(1, 1000))
```

You could also [implement `random_bytes()` using PRNG](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/7aae2b9fcfad/Modules/_randommodule.c#l349).

Answer (score 4):

There are many interesting ways to generate randomness without resorting to random (or numpy). For instance, you can use the built in hash function:

```
def rand_generator(seed, N=10**6, a=0, b=10, integer = True):
    '''For a given seed, this function returns N pseudo-random between a and b'''
    rands =[]
    if integer:
        for i in range(N):
            num = int(a+(b-a)*(abs(hash(str(hash(str(seed)+str(i+1)))))%10**13)/10**13)
            rands.append(num)
        return rands
    else:
        for i in range(N):
            num = a+(b-a)*(abs(hash(str(hash(str(seed)+str(i+1)))))%10**13)/10**13
            rands.append(num)
        return rands
```

This will generate a list of uniformly distributed pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 1. Like the random number generators in random and numpy the sequence is fully deterministic for a given seed.

[Histogram of the function's output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWyTl.png)

**This algorithm is in no way cryptographically safe** but it should be sufficient to answer your question.

If storing the entire list undesirable then the same idea can take the form of a  generator expression. After setting the values for a, b, N, and seed as above:

```
randnum = (int(a+(b-a)*(abs(hash(str(hash(str(seed)+str(j+1))))) % 10**13)/ 10**13) for i in range(N))
```

is an iterator which generates the next number in the sequence via

```
>>> next(randnum)
    5
```

This can be made even neater as follows:

```
def random(seed = None, a=0, b=10,  N=10**12, integer=True):
    '''Pass a seed to generate new sequence, otherwise next value is returned.'''
    if seed:
        print("Starting new sequence.")
        global _rand_generator 
        if integer: 
            hash_plus = lambda j: int(a + (b-a)*(abs(hash(str(hash(str(seed) + str(j+1))))) % 10**13)/ 10**13)
        else:
            hash_plus = lambda j: a + (b-a)*(abs(hash(str(hash(str(seed) + str(j+1))))) % 10**13)/ 10**13
        _rand_generator =  (hash_plus(j) for j in range(N))
    try:
        return next(_rand_generator)
    except:
        print("Random seed required.")
```

To generate a random sequence pass a seed to the function.

```
>>> random(42)
Starting new sequence.
    8
```

Call the function again without a seed to yield the next random number/integer in the sequence.

```
>>> for i in range(10): 
...     print(random())
    3
    4
    6
    5
    5
    9
    2
    2
    4
    0
```

To start a new sequence, simply call the function again with a new seed.

```
>>> random(666)
Starting new sequence.
    5
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, and kudos for your thorough 1st answer; but please do not include meta-commentary in answers (edited out).

Comment: Notice only that (hidden in the title) is the requirement for int(egers).

Comment: Good point, I'll add the transformation to int as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you want integers.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(1,1000)
```

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention I cannot import anything. This is one of the rules for this homework. BTW, this is a small part of the homework, it's not like i'm asking you guys to write the program for me. SO please don't get mad at me :)

Comment: You could make a roulette wheel type setup where you have them hit the space bar and read the milliseconds from the computer clock.

Comment: I'd let you pay me for the answer but then you would be doing it for the rest of your life.  Too bad.  Enjoy your homework.  **Hint** read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#method one, set new seed every time random is needed


seed = "seed" #can be int or string, varies between compilings of the game
possibilities = 3 #0,1,2

hash(str(seed))%possibilities

hash(str(0))%3 #single random number between 0,1,2 (inc) seed is 0


#method two, generate a random list of numbers


size = 100 #length of list
possibilities = 2 #0,1

[hash(str(seed))%possibilities for seed in range(size)]

[hash(str(seed))%5 for seed in range(100)] #generates a list of numbers between 0,1,2,3,4 (inc) with the size of 100
hash(" ")%6


[hash(str(seed))%2 for seed in range(100)].count(1) #validity check. output is ~50
```

i wrote this program to help with this problem