# Python Random Function without using random module

Tags: python, function, random, time

I need to write the function -

```
random_number(minimum,maximum)
```

Without using the random module and I did this:

```
import time

def random_number(minimum,maximum):
    now = str(time.clock())
    rnd = float(now[::-1][:3:])/1000
    return minimum + rnd*(maximum-minimum)
```

I am not sure this is fine.. is there a known way to do it with the time?

Comment: Can you clarify on what your requirements are?  What randomness tests does it need to pass?  As it is written, it is hard to know what you are asking.

Comment: Define what you mean by random, for some standard modulo based `rand` are not sufficient, and for some `return 4; //based on a fair dice throw` are.

Comment: Try to image this function needs to be like randrange, is it good enough?

Comment: The way you are doing it, you can very easily get repeated numbers when calling that function in quick succession. You should use the time as a seed, and generate differnet values from that seed. You are basically re-seeding your random number generator each time.

Comment: @ordim Nope it is not enough, define what does "like" mean. Stop going for a loophole and present proper requirements/properties that can be either fulfilled or not.

Comment: Well all I can say is good luck. It is an algorithm that I'm unfamiliar with in which seeds are created in order to produced pseudo random numbers.

Comment: It needs to be run in a loop and work and generate different numbers.. would you do it differently?

Comment: related: [Random int without importing 'random'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22950768/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The thing is I need to do something that somehow uses the time

You could generate randomness based on a [clock drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift#Random_number_generators):

```
import struct
import time

def lastbit(f):
    return struct.pack('!f', f)[-1] & 1

def getrandbits(k):
    "Return k random bits using a relative drift of two clocks."
    # assume time.sleep() and time.clock() use different clocks
    # though it might work even if they use the same clock
    #XXX it does not produce "good" random bits, see below for details
    result = 0
    for _ in range(k):
        time.sleep(0)
        result <<= 1
        result |= lastbit(time.clock())
    return result
```

Once you have `getrandbits(k)`, it is straigforward to get a random integer in range [a, b], including both end points. [Based on CPython Lib/random.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a727eed3a811/Lib/random.py#l214):

```
def randint(a, b):
    "Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points."
    return a + randbelow(b - a + 1)

def randbelow(n):
    "Return a random int in the range [0,n).  Raises ValueError if n<=0."
    # from Lib/random.py
    if n <= 0:
       raise ValueError
    k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
    while r >= n: # avoid skew
        r = getrandbits(k)
    return r
```

Example, to generate 20 random numbers from 10 to 110 including:

```
print(*[randint(10, 110) for _ in range(20)])
```

Output:

```
11 76 66 58 107 102 73 81 16 58 43 107 108 98 17 58 18 107 107 77
```

If `getrandbits(k)` returns `k` random bits then `randint(a, b)` should work as is (no skew due to modulo, etc).

To test the quality of `getrandbits(k)`, [`dieharder`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dieharder.1.html) utility could be used:

```
$ python3 random-from-time.py | dieharder -a -g 200
```

where `random-from-time.py` generates infinite (random) binary stream:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def write_random_binary_stream(write):
    while True:
        write(getrandbits(32).to_bytes(4, 'big'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    write_random_binary_stream(sys.stdout.buffer.write)
```

where `getrandbits(k)` is defined above.

---

The above assumes that you are not allowed to use `os.urandom()` or `ssl.RAND_bytes()`, or some known PRNG algorithm such as  [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) to implement `getrandbits(k)`.

---

`getrandbits(n)` implemented using "`time.sleep()` + `time.clock()`" fails `dieharder` tests (too many to be a coincidence).

The idea is still sound: a clock drift may be used as a source of randomness (entropy) but you can't use it directly (the distribution is not uniform and/or some bits are dependent); the bits could be passed as a seed to a PRNG that accepts an arbitrary entropy source instead. See ["Mixing" section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3532136/4279).

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to read random data in some special file? Under Linux, the file `/dev/urandom' provides a convenient way to get random bytes. You could write:

```
import struct
f = open("/dev/urandom","r")
n = struct.unpack("i",f.read(4))[0]
```

But this will not work under Windows however.

Comment: The thing is I need to do something that somehow uses the time

Answer (score 1):

Idea is to get number between 0 and 1 using time module and use that to get a number in range.Following will print 20 numbers randomly in range 20 and 60

```
from time import time

def time_random():
 return time() - float(str(time()).split('.')[0])

def gen_random_range(min, max):
 return int(time_random() * (max - min) + min)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 for i in range(20):
     print gen_random_range(20,60)
```

Comment: there are at least two issues: (1) `time_random()` tries to return the current fractions of a second that is highly regular (2) `gen_random_range()` may produce wrong results even if `time_random()` were working (producing uniformly distributed `[0,1.)` float numbers) e.g., see [this Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue24567)

Answer (score 1):

---

here we need to understand one thing that
a random varible is generated by using random
values that gives at run time. For that we need
time module

time.time() gives you random values (digits count nearly 17).
we need in milliseconds so we need to multiply by 1000
if i need the values from 0-10
then we need to get the  value less than 10 that means we need below:
time.time%10 (but it is in float we need to convert to int)
int(time.time%10)

---

```
import time

def rand_val(x):

    random=int(time.time()*1000)

    random %= x

    return random

x=int(input())

print(rand_val(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use API? if allowed.

```
import urllib2

def get_random(x,y):
    url = 'http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=[min]&max=[max]&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
    url = url.replace("[min]", str(x))  
    url = url.replace("[max]", str(y))  
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    num = response.read()
    return num.strip()

print get_random(1,1000)
```

Comment: there could be local sources if allowed such as `os.urandom()`, `ssl.RAND_bytes()`. You could use string formating `'min={min}&max={max}'.format(min=x,max=y)` or `urllib.urlencode()` in more complex cases instead of `str.replace()` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def rand(s,n):
    '''
    This function create random number between the given range, its maximum range is 6 digits
    '''
    s = int(s)
    n = int(n)
    list_sec = datetime.datetime.now()
    last_el=str(list_sec).split('.')[-1]
    len_str=len(str(n))
    get_number_elements = last_el[-int(len_str):]
    try:
        if int(get_number_elements)<=n and int(get_number_elements)>=s:
            return get_number_elements
        else:
            max_value = int('9'*len_str)
            res = s+int(get_number_elements)*(n-s)/(max_value)
            return res
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: s is starting point of range and n is ending point of range

Answer (score -1):

---

finding random values between in a range(x,y)

you need to subtract low range from high store at x

then find random from 0-x

then add the value to low range-> lowrange+x(x is random)

---

```
import time
def rand_val(x,y):
   sub=y-x
   random=int(time.time()*1000) 
   random %=sub
   random+=x
   return random
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
print(rand_val(x,y))
```