# How do i get unique and random colors in turtle WITHOUT import random

Tags: python, random, colors, python-turtle

I have a question in which i have to draw turtles however i need each one to be a unique color. There is no limit to the number of turtles how ever i would appreciate at least 50 unique colors. Also the colors should be visually distinct otherwise i would have just added 1 to each (r,g,b) each time.(I am not allowed to import any other module at all)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot import random then using time will be a pretty good alternative to get colors. The python code below gets the current time then extract 24(0xffffff) bits which are then converted to hexadecimal format for color representation.

```
import time

epoch_time = int(time.time())
print(epoch_time)

mask = 0xffffff
color = hex(epoch_time & mask)
print(color)
```

Comment: This is a really smart way to do it! But I am actually not allowed to import ANY other module

Comment: Not sure that this is even possible without importing anything. There is a solution to  [create random number without import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953238/5921207) but that will only work on linux machines.